# Name of an identity for traceless matrices in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, trace, cross-product

While working on a more compact presentation of a derivation in the context of incompressible fluid flow we tried to simplify things by introducing intermediate steps instead of writing out lengthy terms. One result was the following identity dealing with traceless matrices in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is there a name for this, possibly in a more general context?

Let the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ be traceless, i.e., $\mathop{\rm tr}(A) := \sum_{i=1}^3 a_{ii} = 0$. Then

\begin{equation}
x^\top A y = \sum\nolimits_{i=1}^3 (A(x \times e_i))^\top \cdot (e_i \times y).
\end{equation}

Here, $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $e_i$ denote the $i$th unit vector. I proved this by writing everything out explicitly and canceling terms, but the following Python-code also shows this symbolically:

```
from sympy import *

a = Matrix([symbols('a11 a12 a13'), \
            symbols('a21 a22 a23'), \
            symbols('a31 a32 a33')])
x = Matrix(symbols('x1 x2 x3'))
y = Matrix(symbols('y1 y2 y3'))

e = [Matrix([1,0,0]), Matrix([0,1,0]), Matrix([0,0,1])]

res = x.T*a*y \
  - (x.cross(e[0]))*a.T*(e[0].cross(y).T) \
  - (x.cross(e[1]))*a.T*(e[1].cross(y).T) \
  - (x.cross(e[2]))*a.T*(e[2].cross(y).T)

print simplify(res.subs(a[2,2], -(a[0,0]+a[1,1]))) # trace-free
```

Comment: And $^T$ denotes transpose, while $\times$ is the cross-product, correct? If I am understanding correctly, $e_1 = [1 \ 0 \ 0]^T$, $e_2 = [0 \ 1 \ 0]^T$ and $e_3 = [0 \ 0 \ 1]^T$, right?

Comment: Yes, correct. I hope everything else is written unambiguously.

Comment: Are you sure the equality holds? To me, it appears either false or true regardless of the trace of the matrix $A$. Right now, it seems false to me, but I may be missing something.

Comment: Yes, if I made no mistake this should hold. I also added a short code which I used to verify my computations. The matrix being trace-free seems to be crucial and I was hoping that there is a name for this identity.

Comment: Wait a moment: in your code, I read: res = x.T*a*y. Does this mean: $x^T A y$ ? Because you wrote $A^T x \cdot y$ (which is different). Anyway, it should be convenient to take the matrix $A$ outside the summation (it does not depend on the summation index), in order to simplify the code and the readability.

Comment: What do you mean? Whether I write this as $x^T A y$ or $(A^T x)^T y$ or $(A^T x) \cdot y$ should in my opinion not matter. $x \cdot y$ makes only sense here if it is defined as $x^T y$. Alternatively, I can write
\begin{equation}
x^\top A \cdot y = \sum\nolimits_{i=1}^3 (A(x \times e_i))^\top (e_i \times y).
\end{equation}

Comment: Ehm... not exactly: the problem is the order of the operations. $A^T x \cdot y$ may be read in two ways: the first way is $A^T (x \cdot y)$; the second way is $(A^T x)^T y = x^T A y$. The problem is that, letting $\alpha = x \cdot y$, $\alpha$ is a scalar, thus $A^T \alpha = \alpha A^T$. In the first case, you are multiplying a scalar for all the elements of the matrix and the result is a matrix; in the case $x^T A y$, the result is a scalar. This is the reason why $x^T A y$ should always preferred (there is no ambiguity in the notation). Anyway,thanks for clarifying things,now it makes sense.

Comment: Okay, I thought that was obvious, but I see your point now. I edited my question accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Don't worry, it is my fault for not understanding your notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not found the name of the identity above, but I hope my answer can clarify some aspects, possibly where the need for the condition $\text{tr}(A)=0$ arises.

The key point is that the vectors $x,y$ aren't playing an active role. What is actually enforcing the identity regards the matrix $A$ and a certain matrix $B$, which will be defined below.

Preliminarly, observe that the cross product in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can more conveniently be expressed with matrix multiplication. More precisely, the cross product of a generic vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 1}$ for the canonical base vectors $e_i$, with $i=1,2,3$, is of the type

$v \times e_i = C_i v$

where $C_i$ are the following skew-symmetric ($C_i^T = - C_i$) matrices:

$
C_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
C_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
C_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$

Thanks to this fact and by observing that $e_i \times y = -(y \times e_i)$, the initial identity can be rewritten as follows

$
\begin{split}
x^T A y &= \sum_{i=1}^3 (x \times e_i)^T A^T (e_i \times y) = - \sum_{i=1}^3 (x \times e_i)^T A^T (y \times e_i) = - \sum_{i=1}^3 (C_i x)^T A^T (C_i y) \\
&= - \sum_{i=1}^3 x^T \underbrace{C^T_i}_{ = - C_i} A^T C_i y = \sum_{i=1}^3 x^T C_i A^T C_i y = x^T \underbrace{\left( \sum_{i=1}^3 C_i A^T C_i \right)}_{=B} y
\end{split}
$

where the matrix $B$ has been stated. Now, the identity is of an easy form, from which

$
x^T A y = x^T B y \iff x^T(A-B)y = 0
$

and observe that the left-hand side must hold for all vectors $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 1}$. Thus, it follows that the identity holds iff $A-B=\mathbf{O}$, where $\mathbf{O}$ is the zero matrix. Now, observe that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^3 C_i^2 = -2 I_3
$$
where $I_3$ is the identity matrix of order 3. Using the properties of the trace, it follows that
$$
(*) \quad \text{tr}(B) = -2 \text{tr}(A)
$$
Now, $A-B=\mathbf{O} \Longrightarrow \text{tr}(A - B)=0$. Using $(*)$ and defining the matrix $D=A-B$, we get

$
\text{tr}(D) = 3 \text{tr}(A)
$

which is equal to zero iff $\text{tr}(A)=0$.

---

**Old proof**. In general, what holds true is the following

$
a_{ij} = b_{ij} \quad \forall i \neq j
$

that is, the matrix $B$ differs from the matrix $A$ only for the elements on the main diagonal. This can be proven by direct computation and is always true, regardless of the trace of $A$. Moreover, it can proven (by direct computation) that the matrix $D = A - B$ is a diagonal matrix whose elements on the main diagonal are all equal to the trace of the matrix $A$. In other words,

$
D = \begin{bmatrix} \text{tr}(A) & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \text{tr}(A) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \text{tr}(A)
\end{bmatrix} = \text{tr}(A) I_3
$

Thus, the following fact can be proved: *the identity in the original question, i.e., $x^T D y=0$, holds true if and only if $D$ is the zero matrix*. But $D$ is the zero matrix if and only if $\text{tr}(A)=0$.

I hope this can, at least, help to give you a different perspective.

Comment: +1. This is indeed a nice way of discussing the need for the trace-free condition. In my derivation this simply popped up as a necessary condition at some point, but you found a much more elegant way to describe this. Thanks!

Comment: (+1). I think you can simplify the proof that $A$ needs to be traceless at the end. $A-B=0$, only if: $\text{tr}(A-B)=0$, and: $\text{tr}(B)=-2\text{tr}(A)$, by the linearity and cyclic properties of the trace and by: $\sum_i C_i^2=-2I_3$ which is (up to a sign) known as the Cashmir invariant of $SO(3)$; $C_i$ are up to a sign the 3dim rep of the Lie algebra $so(3)$. So, $\text{tr}(D)=3\text{tr}(A)$. This removes $A$ from direct computation.

Comment: @GrahamHesketh: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately, although I understand the basics of Lie algebra, I'm not well-versed in it (you meant *Casimir invariant*, right?). Somehow, during the proof, I noticed that the $C_i$ are related to Lie algebra (and they are closely related to orthogonal projection matrices). However, in order to avoid trivial mistakes, I skipped that connection (I always avoid writing something I do not feel confident about, even if I know it). Anyway, I will edit my post according to your contributions.

Comment: Yeah I meant Casimir :)

Comment: This sounds interesting! Do you by any chance know a painless introduction to the elements of Lie algebra involved here?